# Backup Mails to new server

Tags: centos, email, migration

I have a custom domain hosted with Microsoft Outlook mail service. now they are not offering creating new accounts under my domain and I decided to move new server. so I configure all the things with new VPS server and all the things working properly without any issue.

now I need to transfer all my mails in my outlook account to my new server. new server have roundcube web interface and need to know is there any way to do this transfer process.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with imapsync. It will be something like this:

```
imapsync --host1 HOST1... --host2 HOST2 --prefix2 "
Folders/" --regextrans2 's/Folders//'
```

Take a look [here](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/)